# Linq запрос для множественного выбора

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin

Есть коллекция

```
List<Plane> planesAll = PlaneCollection.GetPlane();
```

Выбранная позиция с события

```
selectedPlaneBR = planes[e.Position].BR;
```

Так вот данный `BR` в коллекции может быть от `1.0` до `10.0` и варианты могут быть `1.0`, `1.3`, `1.7`, `2.0`, `2.3`, `2.7`, `3.0` и т.д. до `10.0`. 
Надо сделать так, чтобы при выборе пользователя варианта, LINQ возвратил все объекты коллекции с разбросом `+-1`. То есть при выборе `2.3` надо вернуть коллекцию, в которой будут все элементы от `1.3` до `3.3`. Данная коллекция передается в `ListView`. Мой метод:

```
var planevar = 
    from p in planesAll
    where p.BR==selectedPlaneBR
    select p; 

planespotential = planevar.ToList<Plane>();
```

Как сделать чтобы выполнялись все условия и возвращался результат, который можно записать в `.ToList<T>()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что достаточно внести изменения в условие выборки и вы получите необходимый результат. К примеру так:

```
var planevar = 
    from p in planesAll
    where (p.BR >= (selectedPlaneBR - 1)) && (p.BR <= (selectedPlaneBR + 1))
    select p;
```

То есть выбрать элементы в интервале `selectedPlaneBR +-1`, на всякий случай условия заключил в скобки для ясности. Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

- [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)
- [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Вторую ссылку дал, потому что считаю Method Syntax более удобным, чем Query Syntax. Посмотрите, почитайте, думаю не помешает. Для примера:

```
var planevar = planesAll
    .Where(p => p.BR >= (selectedPlaneBR - 1) && p.BR <= (selectedPlaneBR + 1))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо большое. А то я пробовал вот так
where  p.BR == selectedPlaneBR - 1.0 &&
                            p.BR == selectedPlaneBR + 1.0
И оно скорее всего искало аргумент, который сразу подходит под два условия

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Planes.Linq.Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var planesAll = new List<Plane>()
            {
                new Plane() { BR = 1.7 },
                new Plane() { BR = 2.0 },
                new Plane() { BR = 2.3 },
                new Plane() { BR = 2.7 },
                new Plane() { BR = 3.0 },
                new Plane() { BR = 3.3 },
                new Plane() { BR = 3.7 },
                new Plane() { BR = 4.0 },
                new Plane() { BR = 4.3 },
                new Plane() { BR = 4.7 },
                new Plane() { BR = 5.0 },
            };

            double selectedPlaneBR = 3.0;
            double step = 1.0;

            var selectedPlanes =
                from p in planesAll
                where p.BR <= selectedPlaneBR + step && p.BR >= selectedPlaneBR - step
                select p;

            foreach (var item in selectedPlanes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Plane
    {
        public double BR { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return BR.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```